# data is printed in a second row, fortran

Tags: fortran

I have the following write statement in a fortran code:

```
    write(4,'(7f20.4)'),x(i,1), x(i,2),x(i,3),x(i,4),x(i,5),x(i,6),x(i,7),x(i,8),x(i,9)
```

I'd like to have the complete set of values printed in a single line, however I'm getting the two last values in a second.

I've tried `advance=no` already and the issue persists.

Comment: Your format string specifies 7 items to print, but you provide 9.  I think your first effort to solve your problem ought to be to edit the format string.

Comment: I can confirm the problem is, indeed, the number of elements set to 7 instead of 9. Changing to 9 will print all 9 elements in a single row.

Answer (score 1):

Fortran 2008 introduced the *unlimited-format-item*, which is **(format-items)* (in other words, '*' is like a repeat count).

Your compiler (you didn't say which you are using) may support this.

In the (621-page) [Working Document](http://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007r1.pdf),
Note 10.7 explains further:

"The effect of an *unlimited-format-item* is as if its enclosed list were preceded by a very large repeat count. There is no file positioning implied by *unlimited-format-item* reversion. This may be used to write what is commonly called a comma separated value record.

For example,

```
WRITE( 10, ’( "IARRAY =", *( I0, :, ","))’) IARRAY
```

produces a single record with a header and a comma separated list of integer values."

Here's another example - a full program - using the line you gave us above

```
Program test
  Implicit None
  Integer, Parameter :: i = 1
  Real, Parameter :: x(i, 9) = reshape( [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [1,9] )
  Write (4, '(*(f20.4))') x(i, 1), x(i, 2), x(i, 3), x(i, 4), x(i, 5), &
    x(i, 6), x(i, 7), x(i, 8), x(i, 9)
End Program
```